# What's the best pathfinding algorithm in complexity?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, depth-first-search

I need to implement a pathfinding algorithm in one of my programs. The goal is to know whether a path exists or not. As a consequence, knowing the path itself isn't important.

I already did some researches and I am not sure which one to pick. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511118/is-a-the-best-pathfinding-algorithm) post have been telling that a DFS or a BFS would be more suitable for this kind of programs but I'd rather have confirmation knowing the exact situation. I also would be interested in knowing the complexity itself of the program, but I guess I can find this. It's fine if it's not shared.

Here's the graph I am using: let's say I have a x*y grid with zones the path can and cannot take.
I want to know if there is an existing path that starts from the top of the graph and ends on the bottom of the graph. Here's an example with the path in red:

[image: Example]

I believe DFS is the best in complexity but I also am not sure exactly how to implement it knowing the different start points the path can take. I am not sure if it's better to launch the DFS on each of the different points the path can start or if I add a layer of zones the path can take to let one test work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different approaches that you can take here. Assuming that the grids you're working with are of roughly the size that you're showing above, and assuming you aren't, say, processing millions of grids at once, chances are that both breadth-first search and depth-first search would work equally well. The advantage of breadth-first search is that it will find the shortest path from anywhere in the top to anywhere in the bottom; the disadvantage is that it typically requires more memory than depth-first search. But again, if you're working with grids on the order of, say, hundreds or thousands of cells each, chances are that this memory overhead isn't going to be too much of a problem. I'd say to pick whichever algorithm you feel most comfortable working with and go with it.

As for how to implement a search from "anywhere in the top" to "anywhere in the bottom," you can achieve this in a few different ways.

1. If you're using a depth-first search, you can run one depth-first search from each of the cells in the top row and search for a path down to the bottom row. DFS requires you to maintain some information about which cells have and have not been visited. If you recycle this same information across all the calls to DFS, you'll ensure that no two calls do any duplicated work, and so the resulting solution should be very efficient, running in time O(mn) for an m × n grid.
2. If you're using a breadth-first search, the modification is pretty straightforward: instead of just enqueuing a single start point in the queue at the beginning of the search, enqueue every cell in the top row at the beginning of the search. The BFS will then naturally explore all possible paths starting anywhere in the top row.
3. Both of these ideas can be thought of in a different way. Imagine your grid is a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) where each cell is a node and edges correspond to pairs of adjacent cells. You can then add in a new node that sits above the top row of the grid and is connected to each of the nodes in the top row. You then add in a new node that sits just below the bottom row and is connected to each of the nodes in the bottom row. Now, if there's a path from the new top node to the new bottom node, it means that there's a path from some node in the top row to some node in the bottom row, so doing a single search in this graph will be sufficient to check if a path exists. (Fun fact: the two above modifications to DFS and BFS can each be thought of as implicitly doing a search in this new graph.)

There's another option you might want to consider that's fairly easy to implement and imperceptibly less efficient than DFS or BFS, and that's to use a [disjoint-set forest data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to determine what's connected. This data structure supports two kinds of queries:

- Given two cells, mark that there's a way to get from the first cell to the second. ("Union")
- Given two cells, determine whether there's a path between them, which can be a direct path or could be formed by chaining together multiple other paths. ("Find")

You could implement your connectivity query by building a disjoint-set forest, unioning together all pairs of adjacent cells, and then unioning together all nodes in the top row and unioning all nodes in the bottom row. Doing a "find" query to see if any one of the top nodes is connected to any of the bottom nodes will then solve your problem. This will take time O(mn α(mn)) for a function α(mn) that grows so slowly that it's essentially three or four, so it's effectively as efficient as BFS or DFS.

Comment: I like the disjoint-set solution for this problem.  With a little care you can do it row-by-row with very little memory.  You only need to remember two rows worth of sets if union() never points links upwards, and if you only make sets for runs of passable cells, then there are at most ceil(width/2) sets per row...  so an array of width+2 integers is all the extra memory you need.  With the additional advantage of examining each adjacent pair only once, this can probably be the fastest algorithm in the worst case.