# What is the best pathfinding algorithm for given map and rules?

Tags: python, path, path-finding

I am given a map that looks like so:

[image: pathfinding map]

Every node is connected with its horizontal and vertical (not diagonal) neighbors and all connections have the same cost.

I want to find the best path, from one location to a set of end locations (the one which can be reached quickest). Also note that every node has the ability to be blocked and and thus not be used as a node in the path.

What would be the most efficient algorithm to solve this problem with?

I have thought of maybe A* but find it difficult to apply the multiple endpoint rule.

Comment: This SO question might help you, very high quality answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511118/is-a-the-best-pathfinding-algorithm

Comment: Since you have an undirected, equal weights graph, a simple Bread-First Search algorithm will do the job. Alternatively, you can use Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: I think this is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: For grids, check out things like Jump Point Search and RSR. Also A* works fine with multiple endpoints, just take the minimum of all heuristics.